# ImmutableJs with Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

Is it possible to use [immutablejs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) like this:

**Modal**

```
class PeriodModel {
    constructor(
        id,
        title,
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }
}

export default PeriodModel;
```

**ImmutableJs**

```
let immutable = Map(new PeriodModel(1, 'title!'));
```

Or is it not immutable anymore? Normally I would do it like this:

```
let immutable = Map({ id: 1, title: 'title!'});
```

Please let me know if this is good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say if it's good practice or not, but your way of doing it doesn't seem to work; it doesn't make an Immutable Map, it just makes a PeriodModel.

I added a method to your class, `toObject` that returns a plain object of the class's properties.

```
class PeriodModel {
    constructor(
        id,
        title,
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    toObject() {
        return {
        id: this.id,
        title: this.title
      }
    }
}

const periodMap = Immutable.fromJS(new PeriodModel(1, 'title!').toObject());
const periodMapWithoutMethod = Immutable.fromJS(new PeriodModel(1, 'title!'));
```

`periodMap` will be an Immutable Map but `periodMapWithoutMethod` will be a plain object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re looking for is called `Record`.
It is a data structure provided the library that has explicit fields and is suited specifically for what you’re trying to do.

On the other hand, `Map` objects are just generic containers. You should pick which one you prefer, `Record` objects become really useful with Typescript/Flow.